# TFS Web Access - Iteration Capacity - "Copy Capacity Information from the previous iteration" disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-web-access

Within TFS Web Access 2012, when setting the capacity for the sprint, there is a button that says "Copy Capacity Information from the previous iteration".  For one of our Team Projects, the button is disabled:

[image]

All other features of Web Access seem to work fine.  This Team Project was created in TFS 2010 using the Agile template, and then migrated into TFS 2012.  However, we have other Team Projects that are similar, and this button is enabled for them.

Does anyone know what is required for this button to be enabled?

Comment: Have you noticed this behaviour across multiple sprints, or just the current one?

Comment: Do you _have_ capacity information in the previous sprint?

Comment: Do you have the Previous Sprints "Ticked" in the team's iteration configuration and visible under "Backlogs/Past"?

Comment: DaveShaw, you're correct.  In order to enable that button, you have to have a previous sprint checked in the Team Project iterations setup.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In playing around with it some more, we discovered the problem.  In order to enable that button, you have to have a previous sprint checked in the Team Project iterations setup.